# Can you play Metal Gear Rising at 1600x900?

Tags: metal-gear-rising-revengeance

I've recently bought *Metal Gear Rising: Revengeance* and I have a 1600x900 monitor. However, the resolution is not available in the game. It maxes out at 1333x768.

How can I increase the resolution to 1600x900?

Answer (score 1):

There are preset resolutions. After 1333x768 there is 1680x1050.
But this mod should help you https://steamcommunity.com/app/235460/discussions/0/619574421437011967/
(All I did is google "mgr custom resolution", this is first result and people seem to confirm it works)

Also remember this, when using the fix:

> You have to re-select the resolution each time you boot up the game.
>   It's annoying, but it's due to the way the game tries to autodetect
>   the resolution on the display list it should use. (i.e., if you use
>   1600x900 and boot up in that resolution, the game will try to cap it
>   to the next lowest resolution, 1366x768)

Answer (score 0):

The maximum resolution supported by MGR:R is 1920 x 1080 (1080p). According to [This blog post](http://www.destructoid.com/resolution-cap-on-metal-gear-revengeance-circumvented-268727.phtml) the ability to increase resolution past 1920 x 1080 is not supported. Someone has managed to modify the game to do it but they will not be releasing the mod because they believe the developers are releasing a patch.

Comment: 1600x900 is lower than 1920x1080 in both dimensions...

Comment: What does that have anything to do with the answer to the question

Comment: You're saying you can't increase the resolution past 1920x1080. 1600x900 is lower than 1920x1080. So you don't need to increase it past that resolution, so I'm not sure what point this answer has.

Comment: @MarkHenderson he cannot play at max resolution because of his monitor, that is the point of the answer, and the correct answer to his question

Comment: His monitor resolution is 1600x900. This is lower than 1920x1080. He says he can't set it to above 1333x768 (I think he means 1366x768). He doesn't want to play it at 1920 or above. He wants to play at 1600x900.

Comment: @MarkHenderson he cant set it to the resolution higher than this because his monitor does not supprt vertical resolution of 1080, thus the max he can play at is 1366x768.